# What is the way in Parse (iOS) to get a query key value other than the id?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am currently using parse to develop an iPhone app and I got this code:
I have a Class called "Event" and has a field called "EventName"

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Event"];
[query selectKeys:@[@"EventName"]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu scores.", (unsigned long)objects.count);
        // Do something with the found objects
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
        }
    }
}];
```

This works perfectly, but i get the object's IDs instead of the event names which is what i want.

EDIT :

So far I got this inside the IF statement

```
self.eventArray = [objects valueForKey:@"EventName"];
        for(int i=0; i<10 ; i++){
            NSLog(@"%@", eventArray[i]);
            }
```

by doing that the question got solved.

Comment: You don't have to loop through them, just use NSLog(@"%@", self.eventArray); and the way you would access them is `[self.eventArray objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];` or otherwise if your not using it in a tableView

Comment: I am actually using a tableviewcontroller, but yeah its another way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is use the objects array that was retuned from finding the objects and pass them into your array by using `valueForKey`.

So it would be

```
  if (!error) {
    self.yourEventNameArray = [objects valueForKey:@"EventName"];
  }
```

Comment: Btw. You've NSLogged objects.objectId that's why that's what's getting outputted into your log

Comment: Yeah i wanted to get something from the query and the easiest was the IDs. Im trying your solution

Comment: Please update code in your question so it benefits everyone in SO. People are unlikely to skim through comments

Comment: Just NSLog the array. It already outputs the entire column as strings